# Python / pymeep / ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'pymeep'

Tags: python, conda, meep

Was installing `pymeep` per https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation/

used:

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
bash miniconda.sh -b -p <desired_prefix>
export PATH=<desired_prefix>/bin:$PATH
```

and

```
conda create -n mp -c conda-forge pymeep
conda activate mp
```

However, `python -c 'import meep'` results in `ModuleNotFoundError:  No module named 'pymeep'`.  Interactive `python` has the same issue.

I listed the installed packages using `conda list` and it is certainly present on the list.

*How do I tell if this is a problem with `pymeep` or a problem installing with `conda` or ???*

Comment: Can't replicate. Are you sure you typed `python -c 'import meep'`? The error message you show indicates that instead you typed `import pymeep`. The module name should be `meep`.

Comment: simple enough, use `which python` to check which python your terminal is using then you will know :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that installing Anaconda after Miniconda destroyed the path to packages.  A fresh install with only Miniconda resolved the issue.